# "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" crash and Freezes app in new IOS 10.2 and Rejected in the app

Tags: ios, store

Hello I'm crazy about this problem, my app was rejected in the app store because they could not open in devices with ios 10.2 it hangs on the home screen, I did you found several solutions with goal change

`<meta "Content-Security-Policy" content = "default-src gap: // ready file: // * *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: *; style-src 'Self' 'unsafe-inline' *; img-src 'self' data: blob: *; media-src 'self' mediastream: blob:; connect-src * blob: ">`

but not worked out I heard you say it Works without Plugin and then I simply made 9 builder until I figured out which plugin caused the error and is exactly without it everything works and it causes an error soon on the white screen , Until somebody else of the plugin solves the problem the way is to use other unofficial plugins temporarily, I hope someone finds the solution fast because 99% of apps in phonegap use this plugin.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @LokeshSuthar Hello, yes the solution is in the answer just below

Answer (score 0):

Hello I discovered the source of the problem, I was successfully using the preference name = "AutoHideSplashScreen" value = "false"  option to manage the time of my splash by the code, however from 10.2 something goes wrong and the screen So I had to re-include the option to auto hide as true, so the app does not crash any more follows the full list of splash screen preferences: preference name = "AutoHideSplashScreen" value = "true

Plugin version Config.xml

```
<Plugin name = "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source = "npm" spec = "4.0.1" />
<Preference name = "SplashScreen" value = "screen" />
<Preference name = "AutoHideSplashScreen" value = "true" />
<Preference name = "ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value = "true" />
<Preference name = "FadeSplashScreen" value = "false" />
<Preference name = "FadeSplashScreenDuration" value = "1.0" />
<Preference name = "SplashScreenDelay" value = "100" />
<Preference name = "SplashScreenBackgroundColor" value = "# FE5D01" />
<Preference name = "SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value = "true" />
```

and code app.js

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();                      
    });
```